# Typo in Spivak Calculus on Manifolds?

Tags: manifolds

In the proof of theorem 5.2 of Spivak's calculus on manifolds, he invokes the inverse function theorem for a function g that he defines there without ever assuming that it was continuously differentiable. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $g$ is defined as
$$g(a,b)=f(a)+(0,b)$$
with $f$...

Comment: f is a coordinate system which he assumes to be differentiable but not continuously differentiable

Comment: At least part way through Spivak, the author states that he will henceforth use "differentiable" to mean "infinitely differentiable".

Comment: @user68432, see the first paragraph of Ch. 5.

Comment: Ok, thanks Christopher. And you too Martin!